# React + Express + Serve Static Trailing Slash

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

This is hobby project so I am trying to save cost and run all of one server. On dev machine I start Express.js on port 3000 and start CRA on port 3001 with `"proxy": "http://localhost:3000",` in CRA's package.json and life is good.

Frontend is basic CRA project with it's own router

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/whatever" element={<Whatever />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Backend is Express.js with express router, idea being that `/` serves built CRA app, then API routes are checked and finally if that fails to match anything, the backend will return CRA app and let CRA's router figure out what is going on.

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import serveStatic from 'serve-static';

const router = express.Router(),
      root = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..');

const frontendPublicPath = path.join(root, '..', 'frontend', 'build');

router.use('/', serveStatic(frontendPublicPath));
router.use('/api/user', (req, res) => res.json(req.socket.remoteAddress));
router.use('/api/admin/esi/fetch', ensureAuthenticated, admin.fetchEndpoints);
router.use('/api/admin/esi/update', ensureAuthenticated, admin.updateEndpoints);

router.use('*', serveStatic(frontendPublicPath));
app.use('/', router);
```

This setup works like a charm, with one problem. On production server (heroku) it builds static frontend and serves it to the client, however, there are trailing slash issues

If you request directly `https://example.org`, you get `https://example.org`
If you request directly `httts://example.org/page`, you get `https://example.org/page/` and **301 redirect**

If you request directly `https://example.org`, you get `https://example.org` and if you then use link on page to go to `httts://example.org/page`, you get `httts://example.org/page` because routing in this case is done by CRA alone and there is no backend request.

On localhost, this redirect never happens

**I am trying to figure out how to get rid of the 301 redirect in this setup.**

Things tried:

Changing `express.Router()` to `express.Router({ strict: true })` doesn't seem to do anything here, because as expected, the redirect comes from `serveStatic`

Changing

```
router.use('/', serveStatic(frontendPublicPath, { redirect: false }));
...
router.use('*', serveStatic(frontendPublicPath, { redirect: false }));
```

It works as expected on localhost. However, on production, I can only access `https://example.org` and then navigate within CRA as expected, but any deep link fails. There is no longer 301 redirect, but asking for `httts://example.org/page` will say `Cannot GET /page`, which is unexpected since I would assume it would fail all the routes until it hits `*` route and just serves CRA app? If I do request `httts://example.org/page/` then it works again, but I would prefer to get rid of `/` all together.

Is there something obvious I am missing here?

Comment: Do you have a seperate `${FOLDER}/index.html` file for every route, I think it is trying to route you to a folder and since the basic route `/` has an `index.html` file it will serve this

Comment: If above is not the case and you want `react-router` to do the routing I think you need to always serve the `index.html` from the `build` folder. `react-router` should be able to do the routing for you.

Comment: there is only one index.html file

Comment: I found a code example that does the following `router.get('*', (req, res) => { res.sendFile(pathToIndexHtml); });` I think this is what you need, when going to `/page` now it is trying to go to a `page` dist in your `build` folder which does not exist. Weird that it does work on localhost though

Comment: Of course! Makes sense! Thank you, that worked! Can you post it as regular answer and I will mark it as accepted answer?

Comment: Done thanks :-) and happy programming!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When routing to a specific route using `serveStatic` it will try and find a folder within the selected folder so in this case it is trying to find a folder named `page` in your `build` folder, when routing to a folder it searches for an `index.html` file this is the reason the basic route `/` works and others not. `React-router` handles the routing for you so you just need to serve the `index.html` for it. I found this example somewhere which seems to do what you are looking for

```js
router.get('*', (req, res) => { 
    res.sendFile(pathToIndexHtml); 
});
```

Comment: Only change in my code base was  
`router.use('*', serveStatic(frontendPublicPath));`  to  
`router.use('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(\`${frontendPublicPath}/index.html\`));`. 

Neat, elegant and simple. Thx!